# Recompra de producto con fechas en PHP

Tags: php

Mi problema es que tengo un array con productos que estan definidos por un codigo y cada codigo es un array que tiene las fechas en las cuales se compro dicho producto. Para productos que tienen dos o mas fechas tengo que calcular el promedio de tiempo de  cada cuanto compra dicho producto y luego a la ultima fecha de compra sumarle ese resultado para deducir la proxima recompra de producto. Paso la forma del array:

```
array(3) {
  [101]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-02-01"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
  }
  [102]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
  }
  [103]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-15"
  }
}
```

Mi idea es que devuelva todos los productos con dos o mas comprar y su fecha estimada de recompra, mi problema es no saber como manejar las fechas dentro del array para sacar el promedio y mostrarlas con el codigo de producto.

Con lo que tengo logro devolver un array con las fechas aumentas ya a la fecha de recompra, como podria agregarle el codigo a cada fecha de recompra? Y si ven alguna correcion para hacer agradezco que me lo aclaren:

```
function diferenciaDeFechasEntreCompras($fechas){

        $date1 = date_create(reset($fechas));
        $date2 = date_create(next($fechas));
        $diff = $date1 ->diff($date2);

        $promedio= $diff->days;

        return $promedio;
    
}



function fechaEstimadaDeRecompra($comprasConLaFecha){
    
    $arrayConProductoYFechaDeRecompra = array();

    foreach ($comprasConLaFecha as $fechas) {

        if (count($fechas)>=2) {

            $arrayConProductoYFechaDeRecompra[][]=
            date("Y-m-d",strtotime(end($fechas)."+". diferenciaDeFechasEntreCompras($fechas)."days")); 
        
        }
    }
        
    return $arrayConProductoYFechaDeRecompra;

}
```

PROBLEMA: Solo consigo que me de este array

```
array(1) { [101]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "2020-04-01" [1]=> string(10) "2020-04-30" } }
```

Pero solo muestra el codigo de un producto, no me sale la del segundo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar este código, si he entendido bien lo que propones.

Dado que son varios cambios considerables, he puesto comentarios en cada parte.

Lo que haría esta función sería:

1. Recibir por referencia tu array original
2. Verificar si hay dos o más fechas en el array
3. Comparar la diferencia de días entre la primera y la última fecha
4. Crear una nueva fecha y agregarla en el array, bajo la clave `nextDate`

Esto permitiría que los datos originales no sean sobre-escritos, por si se necesitan para otra cosa. Sin embargo, si quieres sobre-escribir los datos, puedes hacerlo, en ese caso simplemente tendrías que modificar el objeto `$last` en cada caso y no crear `$nextDate`.

```
/*
    Aquí $mDates se pasa por referencia
    Esto puede hacerse de otro modo, según te lo requieran o no
    La idea aquí es agregar una realidad nueva en el objeto
    que es la próxima fecha de compra
*/
function getNextDate(&$mDates) {
    /*
        Pasamos $items por referencia con &
        para poder modificar el mismo objeto
        Esto puede hacerse de otro modo si conviene
    */
    foreach ($mDates as &$items){
        /*
            Verificamos si hay dos o más items
        */
        if(count($items)>1){
            /*
                Obtenemos el primero y el último
                y al mismo tiempo creamos un objeto DateTime con c/u
            */
            $first = new DateTime(reset($items));
            $last = new DateTime(end($items));
            /*
                Calculamos el intervalo de días
            */
            $interval = $first->diff($last);
            /*
                Creamos un nuevo objeto fecha
                clonando la última y sumándole el intervalo
            */
            $nextDate = (clone $last)->add($interval);  

            /*
                Agregamos ese objeto al array bajo la clave nextDate
                NOTESE que estamos agregando un objeto DateTime directamente
                Luego podrá usarse como tal en cualquier contexto
            */
            $items['nextDate']=$nextDate; 
        }
    }
}
```

### Prueba

Para llamar la función sería así más o menos:

```
getNextDate($mDates);
```

Aquí `$mDates` sería tu array de fechas. Y luego, haces un `var_dump` del mismo array. La función no tiene `return` porque se está pasando el objeto por referencia, lo cual significa que podrá ser modificado, como de hecho ocurre.

Para la prueba, simplemente, seguido de la llamada a la función:

```
var_dump($mDates);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  [101]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-02-01"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
    ["nextDate"]=>
    object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2020-04-30 00:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
  [102]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2020-03-01"
    ["nextDate"]=>
    object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2020-04-30 00:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
  [103]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2020-01-15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Claro entiendo el unico error que veo es que en la parte del codigo es  `$last = new DateTime(end($items));` deberia ser next en vez de `end` porque se necesita calcular entre fechas y no de la primera a ultima. Podrias ver mi funcion `fechaEstimaDeRecompra` porque en esa funcion me da el array que estoy mostrando pero solo con el producto 101 y la segunda fecha no tiene el otro producto que se repite no se si me explico bien pero me gustaria que aparezca algo asi `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [101]=> string(10) "2020-04-01" } [1]=> array(1) { [102]=> string(10) "2020-04-30" } }`

Comment: @Hugo ¿podrías explicar a qué te refieres con *calcular entre fechas*? No logro entender esa parte en tu planteamiento. Pensé que se quería saber la diferencia entre la primera compra y la última y luego sumar esa diferencia a la última compra para saber una posible fecha próxima de compra.

Comment: El entre fechas seria por ejemplo el producto 101 tiene 3 fechas habria que agarrar del valor 1 al 2, no del 1 al 3 porque si no saltearia una compra por eso en tu codigo lo unico que hay que cambiar es el `end` que tiene que ser un `next`, pero eso ya lo pude lograr . Lo que me gustaria saber es como lograr que me quede el array asi `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [101]=> string(10) "2020-04-01" } [1]=> array(1) { [102]=> string(10) "2020-04-30" } } `esto usando las funciones que yo cree me da el array que muestro en la pregunta

Comment: @Hugo no entiendo lo que quieres, ahí hay dos claves de producto, la `101` y la `102` y una fecha para cada uno que no sé a qué corresponden ¿?

Comment: la fecha que aparece es la estimada a recompra, a mi no me da los dos codigos cuando lo hago me da como muestro en la pregunta esto seria: `array(1) { [101]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "2020-04-01" [1]=> string(10) "2020-04-30" } }` y no se que modificacion tengo que hacer para que me quede asi `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [101]=> string(10) "2020-04-01" } [1]=> array(1) { [102]=> string(10) "2020-04-30" } }`

Comment: @Hugo, tendrías que hacer referencia a la llave de cada array al abrir el bucle, algo así: `foreach ($comprasConLaFecha as $k=>$fechas) {` y luego, usar la llave al momento de guardar el array final: `$arrayConProductoYFechaDeRecompra[$k]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime(end($fechas)."+". diferenciaDeFechasEntreCompras($fechas)."days"));`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Marco la pregunta como resuelta!